# How to write a function that pushes an object to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop

I am trying to create a function that takes an object as parameter and pushes it into an array of objects.

```
const listOfProjects = [];

function Project(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.tasks = [];
}
Project.prototype.addProjectToList = function (projectObj) {
  listOfProjects.push(projectObj);
}

function createProject(projectName) {
  const projectObject = new Project(projectName);
  projectObject.addProjectToList(projectName);
}

createProject('Workout');
createProject('Biology');
createProject('JavaScript')
```

I don't know why this returns an array of strings!

Comment: you might missed `projectObject.addProjectToList(projectObject)`

Comment: Did any of the answers help solve your question? If so, please choose one and mark as the answer. If not, please respond with further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need push **this** reference for save the object context, at same time you pass as argument the projectName, not the object itself, if you have the **this** reference, don't pass it like arg.

```js
const listOfProjects = [];

function Project(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.tasks = [];
}
Project.prototype.addProjectToList = function () {
  listOfProjects.push(this);
}

function createProject(projectName) {
  const projectObject = new Project(projectName);
  projectObject.addProjectToList();
}

createProject('Workout');
createProject('Biology');
createProject('JavaScript');

console.log(listOfProjects);
```

Comment: How do I make this method (addProjectToList) work with any array and not only (listOfProjects) array?

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `addProjectToList` with the name instead of the created object.

Change

```
projectObject.addProjectToList(projectName);
```

to

```
projectObject.addProjectToList(projectObject);
```

```js
const listOfProjects = [];

function Project(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.tasks = [];
}
Project.prototype.addProjectToList = function (projectObj) {
  listOfProjects.push(projectObj);
}

function createProject(projectName) {
  const projectObject = new Project(projectName);
  projectObject.addProjectToList(projectObject);
}

createProject('Workout');
createProject('Biology');
createProject('JavaScript')


console.log(listOfProjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pushing the name into the array instead of the newly created object. The confusion probably stemmed from the object having the same name as the instance.

```js
const listOfProjects = [];

function Project(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.tasks = [];
}
Project.prototype.addProjectToList = function (projectObj) {
  listOfProjects.push(projectObj);
}

function createProject(projectName) {
  projectObject = new Project(projectName);
  projectObject.addProjectToList(projectObject);
}

 let projectObject 
createProject('Workout');
createProject('Biology');
createProject('JavaScript')

console.log(projectObject)
console.log(listOfProjects)
```